# Write permissions for assets folder

Tags: linux, apache, silverstripe

My site is served by the user 'sites' and the files are owned by user 'deploy'

The assets folder and contents is set to 775.

When I try to upload a new asset via the web /admin interface in silverstripe, I get an error (empty file upload result). If I set the folder permissions to 777, the asset uploads.

How do I enable the site to write to a folder owned by deploy, without setting insecure 777 permissions?

Comment: I tend to "deploy as" the website owner; if you use e.g. https://deployer.org as your deployment script there are some ways to get permissions for the webserver user; e.g. ACL, chown, chmod

Answer (score 0):

If `deploy` and `sites` are in a same group, you could give 770 permissions instead of 777.

If that is not the case and you cannot have a common group then you don't have much choice... I guess you could use 707, but that doesn't add much security.

Comment: they are both in the same group.  so i thought 775 would be correct? but it gives the error.

Comment: @Will it should be correct. The user sites is running the webserver? Silvestripe is a PHP CMS, does it run with php-fpm or such? If it does, then with what user? Other leads would be SELinux contexts : check /var/log/audit/audit.log if you have SELinux activated. Do you have mod_suexec enabled or such? Can you provide logs?

Comment: php is running as 'sites'. ill try looking at the logs more